# rails migration error - occurs on all migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following error:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > rails generate migration create_locations_users
NameError: undefined local variable or method `create_locations_users' for main:Object
from (irb):1 
...
```

This is occuring for all migrations. Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run the migration from inside of rib or console - run it from command line directly.

Comment: duh ... sorry one of those days

Comment: it happens every now and then.